# AvalonDock : When using DocumentPane binding, the tabs for new DocumentContent items aren't clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I'm trying to bind a DocumentPane to the property ObservableCollection<DocumentContent> DocumentContent, using the xaml below.

```
<ad:DocumentPane Name="documentPane" ShowHeader="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocumentContent, Mode=OneWay}"></ad:DocumentPane>
```

My problem is that when a new DocumentContent object is added to the ObservableCollection, it adds the tab to the DocumentPane correctly, but the tab is not clickable.

Before I switched to data binding I was using document.Items.Add( new DocumentContent() ), which worked as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas why the tabs would not be clickable if they're added via data binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this by moving the Binding to the parent DockingManager element, using DocumentsSource instead of ItemsSource.  Fairly counter-intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for answer. And its true that its not avalon is buggy and not oblivious.